# How can I get to my Arris modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I have an Arris cable modem and an Asus Wireless Router. I need to get to the Arris modem to allow inbound HTTP requests. However, I cannot get to the admin interface of my modem. I've tried the following:

1. `192.168.0.1`
2. `192.168.2.1`
3. `10.0.0.1`

I've also tried bypassing the Router and plugging right into the modem. I grabbed the IP address from the `Router` setting of my Macs 10/100 connection. That didn't work either.

It seems I can't get to this modem, but what's interesting is I **can** get to the modem's status at `192.168.100.1` interestingly.

Comment: Exactly what model of cable modem?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Arris TM822

Comment: As far as I know the status page is all you get. The cable modem is managed by the cable provider.

Comment: @MichaelHampton oh so since it does not have the built-in wireless I don't have to manage it? Does it allow inbound HTTP request by default you think? Or would I have to contact my provider?

Comment: I've got a different Arris model but they all should be the same. If it doesn't have Wi-Fi, there's nothing to manage. It just pushes packets back and forth. If the ISP is blocking inbound traffic, it'll be farther upstream than your cable modem anyway. (Though the reboot button is nice when you want to reboot it and don't want to get up...)

Comment: Most of these are dumb, nothing to manage for the user... Everything would be done in your router.